# Regex and wild characters

Tags: regex, string

I'd like to use the regex

`%[ _]play[ ,_]%`

where `%` is denotes allows some arbitrary string to appear. For example, I'd want to check that this regex appears in some where in some string. Is this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not valid. The easiest way would be to simply remove the percentage signs, because a string doesn't need to match the specified regex exclusively.

This regex:

```
[ _]play[ ,_]
```

will match this string:

```
ABC play,DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

You practically made it yourself. Just need to replace `%` with `.*`

```
 .*[ _]play[ ,_].*
```

**[Edit]**

As Daniel Hilgarth mentioned it does not make sense to use `.*`, if this is just for matching.

Although, if you need to capture start and end separately then you would use expression like this:

```
 (.*)[ _]play[ ,_](.*)
```

It will capture the start and the end as numbered groups.

Comment: It's completely unnecessary and has a performance impact, to pre- and post-fix it with `.*`.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - it depends on what you want to capture and if you want to capture. If this is just for matching, I absolutely agree that `.*` is not required. But if we want to capture something that before and after, we need to specify `.*`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need this for capturing? If the string matches the regex without `.*`, you can just take the whole string, because this is the complete capture of the regex with `.*`. I still see no benefit in using `.*`.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - ic what you mean. You are right. Without making capture groups it does not make sense as it will match whole string. So the capture will always be the input string, if it matched.

Comment: @All. Thanks! I like both answers but I'm afraid can only accept one.